# Google chart in JQueryUI dialog loaded from seperate page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, google-api

I have an ajax function that on success, builds a JQuery modal dialog on success, here is the function:

```
function employeeStatistics(url,id,name){
var tag = $("<div></div>");
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { username: id, name: name },
    success: function(data) {
        tag.html(data).dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: "Statistics for: " + name,
            width: ($(window).width() * 0.9),
            height: ($(window).height() * 0.9),
            close: function() { $(this).remove(); },
            buttons: {
                "Done": function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            }
        }).dialog('open');
    }
});
```

}

the url that it uses is statistics.php which runs a bunch of queries, does some math, and prints some values. I have been wanting to put a chart in the dialog that pops up (using Google Charts API) but I have not been successful.

Here is how the function is called:

```
onclick="employeeStatistics('statistics.php', 'Username', 'DisplayName');
```

The first way I set up the chart was as follows:

**index.php:**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['test', 'value'],
                ['1',     15],
                ['2',      8],
                ['3',      1],
                ['4',      4],
                ['5',      3]
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'My Daily Activities'
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('elchart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    </script>
```

**statistics.php:**

```
<div id="elchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

With this setup I got the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Container is not defined

So then I tried to change it up to look like this:

**index.php:**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
```

**statistics.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['key', 'value'],
        ['1',     15],
        ['2',      8],
        ['3',      1],
        ['4',      4],
        ['5',      3]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

although I didn't get the same error on this one, all it returned was a blank white page, as if everything was deleted (until you refresh).

I have spent the last 3 hours going in circles and reading every possible article on the thing, but I have found no answers.

Is it even possible to load a google chart into a modal dialog that is populated by a different php file from where it was called from?

Sorry if I made this sound confusing, it is hard to visualize it in my head...

Answer (score 2):

Working with a friend he discovered that if you remove

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

and change

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
```

to

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: drawCharts });
```

it works!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

Remove:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Add the `drawChart` function to the open event of the dialog:

```
tag.html(data).dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Statistics for: " + name,
        width: ($(window).width() * 0.9),
        height: ($(window).height() * 0.9),
        close: function() { $(this).remove(); },
        open: function(event, ui){ drawChart(); },
        buttons: {
            "Done": function () {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }
    }).dialog('open');
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort in this, but this did not work. Over the weekend I had a friend take a look at it and he found that if you removed the google callback and added `callback: drawChart` to the `google.load` so it looks like `google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: drawChart });`

Comment: @GrantMartin +1 for being a gent.